# Numerically integrate complex valued function of a real variable and a complex variable

Tags: numerical-integration, complex

I need to numerically integrate a complex valued function of a real variable and a complex variable by the real variable. My integral:

$$ \int^1_{-1}\frac{e^{ix}}{x-z}dx ~~~\text{where}  ~~x \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$$

I'm trying to do this:

```
z := x + I y; NIntegrate[Exp[I x]/(x - z), {x, -1, 1}]
```

But I get the message:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (I E^(I x))/y has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.

How can this integration be done numerically in Mathematica?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE DJNZ! You either need to give `z` a numerical value or use `Integrate` instead of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Very thanks!
I solve a more general problem: I have to integrate a large complex function over several real variables (this is such a parametrization), and I try to understand how to do it in general, and for this I try to make a prototype on a Mathematica. My target - make a calculation without decomposition into imaginary and real parts.

Comment: If your general problem involves Cauchy principal values, you might want to arrange things so that "normal" integrals and principal value integrals are done separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $z = a+ib$, since otherwise you are assuming that $x-z=iy$ which is always imaginary in your question. However, you do not even need to actually specify $z$ in that form. You just need to do this:

```
F[z_?NumberQ] := Integrate[Exp[I*x]/(x - z), {x, -1, 1}, PrincipalValue -> True]
F[1 + 2 I]
F[-I/2]
F[I/3]
F[0]
```

This gives

> \begin{align}
> &e^{-2+i} (\text{Ei}(-2)-\text{Ei}(2-2 i))\\
> &\sqrt{e} \left(-\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2}-i\right)+\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+i\right)-2 i \pi \right)\\
> &\frac{\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{3}+i\right)-\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{3}-i\right)}{\sqrt[3]{e}}\\
> &2 i \text{Si}(1)
> \end{align}

The last example is meant to show how it works when $z$ is real number, in which you need principal value integral. You could also change this to numerical case

```
G[z_?NumberQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[I*x]/(x - z), {x, -1, z, 1}, Method -> PrincipalValue]
```

where you can account for when $z\in (-1,1)$ and you invoke PrincipalValue as "Method" (slightly different syntax than the Integrate command).

Answer (score 1):

```
z := x + I*y;

Integrate[Exp[I*x]/(x - z), {x, -1, 1}]
```

> (2 I Sin[1])/y

If you insist on using `NIntegrate` then you should provide numerical value to `y`?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I wrote "I need to integrate _**numerically**_ complex... ". Yes, but how to provide numerical value for y? How to set complex variable in general?